# Parity 1.7.8 is syncing the last few blocks very slowly

Tags: parity, synchronization, warp-sync

I have been using the parity client to download the ethereum database for the last few days. Despite using the warp sync to download it, I havent been able to download the last few blocks fast enough. It is downloading at the speed the blocks are being mined. If I keep on downloading at this rate I will never be able to achieve a full sync.

This is how i start parity in the CLI:

> parity --snapshot-peers 20 --cache-size 1024 --db-compaction ssd --tracing off --pruning fast --mode active

This is what I am getting so far:

```
2017-11-10 10:55:21  Syncing #4520164 6b14…173e     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2745 Qed  #4522911   16/25 peers    919 KiB chain   62 MiB db  199 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-11-10 10:55:26  Syncing #4520164 6b14…173e     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2745 Qed  #4522911   17/25 peers    919 KiB chain   62 MiB db  199 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-11-10 10:55:36  Syncing #4520164 6b14…173e     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2745 Qed  #4522911   19/25 peers    919 KiB chain   62 MiB db  199 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-11-10 10:55:46  Syncing #4520164 6b14…173e     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2745 Qed  #4522911   18/25 peers    919 KiB chain   62 MiB db  199 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-11-10 10:55:51  Syncing #4520164 6b14…173e     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2745 Qed  #4522911   18/25 peers    919 KiB chain   62 MiB db  199 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-11-10 10:56:02  Syncing #4520165 3f4f…c3cb     0 blk/s    8 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2745 Qed  #4522911   20/25 peers    919 KiB chain   61 MiB db  199 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-11-10 10:56:12  Syncing #4520167 f18d…ba86     0 blk/s    2 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2741 Qed  #4522911   21/25 peers    919 KiB chain   61 MiB db  199 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-11-10 10:56:21  Syncing #4520167 f18d…ba86     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2741 Qed  #4522911   21/25 peers    919 KiB chain   61 MiB db  199 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-11-10 10:56:32  Syncing #4520167 f18d…ba86     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2741 Qed  #4522911   22/25 peers    919 KiB chain   61 MiB db  199 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-11-10 10:56:42  Syncing #4520168 b543…490d     0 blk/s    6 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2741 Qed  #4522911   22/25 peers    919 KiB chain   61 MiB db  199 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-11-10 10:56:52  Syncing #4520168 b543…490d     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2741 Qed  #4522911   23/25 peers    919 KiB chain   61 MiB db  199 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-11-10 10:57:02  Syncing #4520168 b543…490d     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2741 Qed  #4522911   23/25 peers    919 KiB chain   61 MiB db  199 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-11-10 10:57:12  Syncing #4520168 b543…490d     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2741 Qed  #4522911   23/25 peers    919 KiB chain   61 MiB db  199 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-11-10 10:57:22  Syncing #4520169 371c…2573     0 blk/s    6 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2741 Qed  #4522911   24/25 peers    919 KiB chain   61 MiB db  199 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-11-10 10:57:32  Syncing #4520170 6fad…9cd4     0 blk/s    1 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2737 Qed  #4522911   23/25 peers    919 KiB chain   61 MiB db  198 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-11-10 10:57:42  Syncing #4520170 6fad…9cd4     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2737 Qed  #4522911   22/25 peers    919 KiB chain   61 MiB db  198 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-11-10 10:57:52  Syncing #4520170 6fad…9cd4     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2737 Qed  #4522911   22/25 peers    919 KiB chain   61 MiB db  198 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-11-10 10:58:02  Syncing #4520170 6fad…9cd4     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2737 Qed  #4522911   20/25 peers    919 KiB chain   61 MiB db  198 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-11-10 10:58:12  Syncing #4520170 6fad…9cd4     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2737 Qed  #4522911   20/25 peers    919 KiB chain   61 MiB db  198 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-11-10 10:58:22  Syncing #4520170 6fad…9cd4     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+ 2737 Qed  #4522911   21/25 peers    919 KiB chain   61 MiB db  198 MiB queue    2 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
```

I am running the parity 1.7.8 stable client on a windows 10. Is there any way to speed it up? There should be no reason why 3000 blocks should be taking so long

Comment: Is that an SSD or a HDD?

Comment: It is a HDD, and my parity has managed to sync after I left it on after a few days. So it is not an issue now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sync took about 2 days to fully sync, so it is not an issue now. The parity client was just a little slow